# Want to find efficient way to replace multiple switch statements

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
while (1) {
    cout << "Enter the number corresponding to your choice:" << "\n";
    cout << "1 - Go North\n";
    cout << "2 - Go East\n";
    cout << "3 - Go West\n> ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice){
      case 1:
        northAtlantic();
        break;
      case 2:
        southIndian();
        break;
      case 3:
        southPacific();
        break;
      default:
        cout << "Invalid choice. Try again.";
        pressEnter();
    }
  }
```

```
while (1) {
    cout << "Enter the number corresponding to your choice:" << "\n";
    cout << "1 - Go West\n";
    cout << "2 - Go South\n> ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice){
      case 1:
        westArctic();
        break;
      case 2:
        westPacific();
        break;
      default:
        cout << "Invalid choice. Try again.";
        pressEnter();
    }
  }
```

I need a way to put these two switch statements into one function that I can call and put the functions and options into the parameters. The problem with this though is I can't make a function that takes 3 case statements aswell as 2 and it doesn't make any sense.

I tried making a function that takes in both functions and the choices. I would like it so I can enter a number and it will make that many case statements and then I can put the text and the function for those statements.

Comment: A vector of function pointers should do the trick.

Comment: Show us the code that didn't work, rather than the code that does.

Comment: What was the topic of your C++ class, or the chapter in your C++ textbook where this practice problem came from? This will help in pointing you at the correct approach that you're expected to learn from your class, or textbook. There are several different possible C++ topics that this kind of a problem is designed to cover, so we need to know exactly what you're supposed to learn from doing this practice problem, in order not to waste your time with something irrelevant.

Comment: This looks like something that should be completely programmatic. The prompt, the choices, the function being executed should probably share a common API. I would have a matrix or grid of something like a Cell type that all present their potential actions.

Comment: Last time I wrote something similarly in C++, I used an array of pointers for the cardinal directions. Initialize all elements to be null pointers, and assign the suitable location to the correct elements. Then translate the input to an index into the array, and use that element for the next location. Of course, that requires the locations you more to to be objects.

Answer (score 2):

The part that is not the same between the two functions is strings and associated functions. You could use a `std::map` or `std::unorderd_map`, though you actually want to use an index as key to look up the strings and then the functions. Hence a `std::vector` will do.

```
void make_choice(const std::vector<std::string,const std::function<void()>& options) {
     while(1) {
         std::cout << "Enter the number corresponding to your choice:" << "\n";
         for (int i=0;i<options.size();++i) { 
             std::cout << i+1 << options[i].first << "\n";
         }
         int choice = 0;
         std::cin >> choice;
         if (choice > 0 && choice < options.size()) {
               options[i].second();
               break;
         } else {
               std::cout << "Invalid choice. Try again.";
               pressEnter();
         }
     }
}
```

For futher reading I refer you to cppreference, you can read there about [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and because I mentioned it [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [`std::unorderd_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

I suppose with "efficient" you meant "efficient to write". Runtime performance is secondary, as most time will be spent waiting for the user to enter some input.

Last but not least, I didnt add more user input validation than was present in your code. You should check if extraction of an `int` suceeds, because if it fails (eg user entering `foobar`) then the above will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

A loop through a vector of a <function,description> pairs would allow you a menu of arbitrary length and is straightforward to set up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

using Items = vector< pair<function<void()>,string> >;     // Collection of functions with descriptions
//using Items = vector< pair<void(*)(),string> >;     // Alternative with simple function pointers

void northAtlantic(){ cout << "> northAtlantic\n\n"; }     // Whatever you do in quarter of an ocean!
void southIndian  (){ cout << "> southIndian  \n\n"; }
void southPacific (){ cout << "> southPacific \n\n"; }
void westArctic   (){ cout << "> westArctic   \n\n"; }
void westPacific  (){ cout << "> westPacific  \n\n"; }


void menu( const Items &items )
{
   int choice;
   while( true )
   {
      cout << "Enter the number corresponding to your choice (0 to exit):" << "\n";
      for ( int i = 1; i <= items.size(); i++ ) cout << i << " - " << items[i-1].second << '\n';
      cin >> choice;
      if ( choice == 0 ) return;
      if ( choice < 0 || choice > items.size() ) cout << "Invalid choice. Try again.\n\n";
      else                                       items[choice-1].first();
   }
}


int main()
{
   Items items1{ { northAtlantic, "Go North" }, { southIndian, "Go East"  }, { southPacific, "Go West" } };
   Items items2{ { westArctic   , "Go West"  }, { westPacific, "Go South" }                              };
   menu( items1 );
   menu( items2 );
}
```